# Laravel Seeder not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-migrations

I'm running a few seeders during a migration after creating a table. Here's my migration file `create_institutions_table`

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateInstitutionsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('institutions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('code');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });

        $seeder = new InstitutionsSeeder();
        $seeder->run();

        $seeder2 = new UsersSeeder();
        $seeder2->run();

        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('institution_id')->references('id')->on('institutions');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('institutions');
    }
}
```

here's the `InstitutionsSeeder`

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class InstitutionsSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('institutions')->insert([
            'name' => 'Institution One',
            'code' => 'I1',
        ]);

    }
}
```

here's the `UsersSeeder`

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class UsersSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('users')->insert([
            'first_name' => 'Admin',
            'last_name' => 'Istrator',
            'email' => 'admin@example.com',
            'institution_id' => '1',
            'password' => '$2y$10$/wYQaaaaaaagrtyh64gbdt4yuhr32l4VmFHI.sINMR/9LXsj1MTy',
        ]);
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell there's no real difference between the seeders, but the migration fails when trying to instanciate the `UsersSeeder` class while the `InstitutionsSeeder` works fine. This is the exception I'm getting from the `php artisan migrate:fresh` command:

```
   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Class 'UsersSeeder' not found

  at H:\code\MyProject\database\migrations\2019_06_17_224612_create_institutions_table.php:27
    23| 
    24|                 $seeder = new InstitutionsSeeder();
    25|                 $seeder->run();
    26| 
  > 27|                 $seeder2 = new UsersSeeder();
    28|                 $seeder2->run();
    29| 
    30|                 Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    31|                         $table->foreign('institution_id')->references('id')->on('institutions');

  Exception trace:

  1   CreateInstitutionsTable::up()
      H:\code\MyProject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator.php:379

  2   Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator::Illuminate\Database\Migrations\{closure}()
      H:\code\MyProject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator.php:388

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

Why won't the `UsersSeeder` work?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are running your database seeds within your migrations? If not, I would strongly encourage you to run these in Database seeder instead. This will also likely fix your issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible solutions:

1. Check the namespace of your class
2. Run composer dump-autoload: `composer dump-autoload` (You can [read the docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload-dumpautoload) here)

Comment: `composer dump-autoload` did the trick. I'm getting back into the PHP ecosystem, so this is invaluable information, thanks! I realize now that it became out of sync because I copied the file instead of using the respective `php artisan make` commands. 

I understand that while you've outlined the 'by the book' way for seeding data as indicated in the Laravel docs, I am unable to do that for reasons that are beyond the scope of this question/answer, so I will probably edit that part out. Thanks again!

Comment: Happy to help you!

Answer (score 0):

Each time you create a new seeder run `composer dump-autoload` command.
After that just run the seeder using `php artisan db:seed` command.
Hope this will work !